# Javascript Tetris moveRight Issue (Ania Kubow/FCC Tutorial)

Tags: javascript, html, css, tetris

I am following Ania Kubow's tutorial on how to make a Tetris game with Javascript. However, I am stuck at the function moveRight(). I have recheck the syntax and changed the keycode to make sure it was not the key but I can't get my blocks to move right. They move left and down fine however. Here is the code I have so far:

Thanks!

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const grid = document.querySelector('.grid');
  let squares = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.grid div'));
  const ScoreDisplay = document.querySelector('#score');
  const StartBtn = document.querySelector('#start-button');
  const width = 10;

//The Tetrominoes
const lTetromino = [
  [1, width+1, width*2+1, 2],
  [width, width+1, width+2, width*2+2],
  [1, width+1, width*2+1, width*2],
  [width, width*2, width*2+1, width*2+2]
]

const zTetromino = [
  [0, width, width+1, width*2+1],
  [width+1, width+2, width*2, width*2+1],
  [0, width, width+1, width*2+1],
  [width+1, width+2, width*2, width*2+1]
]

const tTetromino = [
  [1, width, width+1, width+2],
  [1, width+1, width+2, width*2+1],
  [width, width+1, width+2, width*2+1],
  [1, width, width+1, width*2+1]
]

const oTetromino = [
  [0, 1, width, width+1],
  [0, 1, width, width+1],
  [0, 1, width, width+1],
  [0, 1, width, width+1]
]

const iTetromino = [
  [1, width+1, width*2+1, width*3+1],
  [width, width+1, width+2, width+3],
  [1, width+1, width*2+1, width*3+1],
  [width, width+1, width+2, width+3]
]

const theTetrominoes = [lTetromino, zTetromino, tTetromino, oTetromino, iTetromino]

let currentPosition = 4;
let currentRotation = 0;

//randomly select a Tetromino and its first rotation
let random = Math.floor(Math.random()*theTetrominoes.length)
let current = theTetrominoes[random][currentRotation];

//draw the  Tetromino
function draw() {
  current.forEach(index => {
    squares[currentPosition + index].classList.add('tetromino')
  })
}

//undraw the Tetromino
function undraw() {
  current.forEach(index => {
    squares[currentPosition + index].classList.remove('tetromino')
  })
}

//make the tetromino move down every second
timerId = setInterval(moveDown, 800);

//assign functions to keyCodes
function control(e) {
  if(e.keyCode === 37) {
    moveLeft()
  } else if (e.keyCode === 38) {
    rotate()
  } else if (e.keycode === 39) {
    moveRight()
  } else if (e.keyCode=== 40) {
    moveDown()
  }
}
document.addEventListener('keyup', control)

//move down function
function moveDown() {
    undraw()
    currentPosition += width
    draw()
    freeze()
}

//freeze function
function freeze() {
  if(current.some(index => squares[currentPosition + index + width].classList.contains('taken'))) {
    current.forEach(index => squares[currentPosition + index].classList.add('taken'))
    //start a new tetromino falling
    random = Math.floor(Math.random() * theTetrominoes.length)
    current = theTetrominoes[random][currentRotation];
    currentPosition = 4
    draw()
  }
}

//move the tetromino left, unless is at the edge or there is a blockage
function moveLeft() {
  undraw()
  const isAtLeftEdge = current.some(index => (currentPosition + index) % width === 0);

  if(!isAtLeftEdge) currentPosition -=1;

  if(current.some(index => squares[currentPosition + index].classList.contains('taken'))){
  currentPosition +=1
}

draw()
}

//move the tetromino right, unless is at the edge or there is a blockage
function moveRight() {
  undraw()
  const isAtRightEdge = current.some(index => (currentPosition + index) % width === width-1)

  if(!isAtRightEdge) currentPosition +=1

  if(current.some(index => squares[currentPosition + index].classList.contains('taken'))) {
    currentPosition -=1
  }

  draw()
}
```

Comment: Does the left move work or it doesn't either?

Comment: Yes, the left works and the down as well.

Comment: Does it give you any error on console?

Comment: No I don't see any errors in the console.

Answer (score 2):

Came across this and it's probably too late, but the control function has a typo, e.keycode === 39 should be e.key**C**ode === 39